# Systemd: locking the console

Tags: systemd, screen-lock

I have a laptop that runs Debian Jessie with only the Linux console - no X server installed.

A recent `dist-upgrade` replaced sysvinit with systemd.

Now I'm trying to get systemd to lock the console when the computer sleeps (this was previously handled by a script in `/etc/pm/sleep.d`.)

I've tried this:

`/etc/systemd/system/screenlock.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock X session using slock
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=<username>
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vlock -ans

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

And then:

```
systemctl enable screenlock.service
```

A similar solution works for me on another computer with X but this isn't working in the console.

How can that be?

Comment: You don't need that.  Look at the [Systemd Sleep.service](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-suspend.service.html)

Comment: The point is that I want my machine locked it suspends or hibernates ...

Comment: `apt-cache search vlock`

Comment: Yep, vlock is a console screen locking program - I want systemd to lock my consoæle with it on hibernate and suspend ...

Comment: The reason its not Working is because the real terminal uses the ACPI sleep function in your BIOS, where as the one working uses the Timer set in your DE.  I dunno of any service that interfaces with ACPI so we will wait...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by using [physlock](https://github.com/muennich/physlock) instead of vlock with the `/etc/systemd/system/screenlock.service` file like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Lock X session using slock
Before=sleep.target

[Service]
User=<username>
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/physlock -d

[Install]
WantedBy=sleep.target
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts in /usr/lib/systemd/system-sleep/ will be executed pre and post suspension|hibernation when using systemctl suspend, so you can add a script to start vlock from there. Lots of detail here in the [ArchLinux Systemd Wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd#Sleep_hooks).